# Get value outside ruby block

Tags: ruby, variables, block

I have

```
arr = [1,2,6,55,226]
arr.each do |a| p a end
```

How is it possible to get `a` outside `do end`?

Comment: What value would you expect it to be?

Comment: all 'a' values ..1,2,6,55,226.Every element of 'each'

Comment: @Katya can you be more specific you are saying to get array values without loop then you need to access the individual elements using its index like arr[0], arr[1] etc.,

Comment: @Katya - can't you just use `arr`? Using a outside of the block does not make any sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @anusha i want loop through array and get value outside it

Comment: @BroiSatse may be im dont explain it correct but what i need it arr.each do|a| value_outside_block=a end and use value_outside_block later

Comment: @Katya then first you need to define value_outside_block variable before the loop but the problem is you will get only the last value if you want all values you will agian need to store them in array, it is not at all recommended

Comment: what do you want to do with the variables outside of the loop?

Comment: @TheChamp use it later for save in db

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just loop through the array again?

Comment: If you want to use your iterator outside the block, use `for`. In general, `Ennumerable#each` is more idiomatic for looping, but this seems to be the one acceptable use of `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Familiarize yourself with scopes.

There are basically 3 scopes in Ruby: class/module/method definition scope, a block scope and a global (a more accurate term is 'script' scope). Scope means 'visibility', a block scope means a variable is not visible anywhere outside the do/end block, class/module/method definition scope means a variable is not visible anywhere outside the class/module/method definition.

Your variable `a` is inside a BLOCK scope (between the do/end) and is only visible only between the do/end and not anywhere outside it.

You can access any element of `arr` by its index:

```
arr = [1,2,6,55,226]
puts arr[0] #=> 1
puts arr[1] #=> 2
puts arr[3] #=> 6
puts arr[4] #=> 226
```

So you don't need a separate variable to access the content of the array when in fact, you can access it via `arr`. If you want to get all the elements of the array in 1 variable, you can use the `join` method:

```
arr = [1,2,6,55,226]
all_elements = arr.join(',')
puts all_elements #=> 1,2,6,55,226
```

Be aware that all_elements is now a String, not an Array. If you want to 'transform' each element, say, increase it by 1, you can do:

```
arr = [1,2,6,55,226]
array_increased_by_1 = arr.map do |each_element|
  each_element + 1
end

p array_increased_by_1 #=> [2, 3, 7, 56, 227]
```

There are many methods of arrays in Ruby and many [useful](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-part-arrays/) [tutorials](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/arrays/) online for familiarizing you with them.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `a` is not visible outside as it is within the block. To get `a` outside you just need to use `arr` again.

if `a` is modified within block and you want to use the new modified value, you can reuse array and assign the new modified value or use a new array to hold those values.

```
arr = [1,2,6,55,226]
arr.each_with_index do |a,i| 
  p i
  arr[i] = a+1 #=> a is processed and modified
end
p arr #=> [2, 3, 7, 56, 227]
```